# Arduino sound effects need assistance

Tags: arduino-uno

Hello!
I'm making a portable game with arduino and i need to play audio files. 
I have them ready in my computer but i want to know if there are any ways to put them inside arduino and play them in a buzzer. 
Always, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PCM Audio. You'll need a library to play the PCM audio data and you'll need to learn how to convert your audio data to PCM. This isn't as hard as it sounds. The link below gives the basics. I'm a Windows users so I used Audacity to generate the PCM audio data. The procedure with Audacity is very similar to the example in the link below.

http://highlowtech.org/?p=1963

Answer (score 1):

If you have actual audio files that you want to play you will need an MP3 player. There are several on the market, some even plug directly onto the Arduino.

If you want to make a buzzing sound for a duration of time for your game, there are cheap buzzers out there that along with a resistor in series (you will need to figure out the value to keep your Arduino safe) that will make noise with a digital write command to whichever pin it is wired to.